# Запуск скрипта по щелчку

Tags: linux

Как в `linux` Запустить скрипт по клику?
Пример скрипта:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $PWD/TEST
```

Comment: что такое клик?

Comment: поставить права *.sh файла как исполняемого

Comment: я писал `chmod u+x`,но по двойному клику(`ubuntu`) открывается текстовый редактор

Comment: В `linux`  нет никакой мыши и никаких кликов. Они есть в линуксовых графических окружениях, и всё зависит от вашего конкретного случая.

Comment: Так вам mime-type надо ассоциировать с приложением / действием. Я думаю, что при смене `bash` на `sh` всё волшебным образом заработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ярлыки" на рабочем столе в linux по сути являются [ini-файлами с расширением `.desktop`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)).

В вашем случае будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MyScript
Path=/usr/local/bin
Exec=my-script.sh
Terminal=true
Categories=System
```

При этом сам скрипт вам в данном случае нужно расположить в `/usr/local/bin/my-script.sh`